# Помогите с JQuery

Tags: jquery, анимация, animate

я не могу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на блок, цвет его краёв менялся на другой цвет, используя `.animate()`, ничего не выходит! (2 строка с данного скрипта), помогите пожалуйста!

```
if ($(".title_text_variant").text() == "Click to open...") {
    $(".main_block_variant").animate({'borderColor': '#5dbf76'}, 500);
    $(".title_text_variant").text("Click to close...");
    return $(".block_variant").slideDown(500);
}
```

Comment: У вас ошикба. Оператор `return` это только для функций в блоку `if` не работает, и будет ошибака

Comment: function actionvariant() {
 if ($(".title_text_variant").text() == "Click to open...") {
  $(".main_block_variant").css("border", "2px solid #5dbf76").slideDown(1000);
  $(".title_text_variant").text("Click to close...");
  return $(".block_variant").slideDown(500);
 }
 
 if ($(".title_text_variant").text() == "Click to close...") {
  $(".title_text_variant").text("Click to open...");
  return $(".block_variant").slideUp(500);
 }
}

Я пишу это в функции, просто отправил кусок кода

Comment: Ничего не понятно по кусочкам, какая к примеру у вас разметка  я вижу три класса `title_text_variant`, `main_block_variant`, `block_variant`. Что как?

Comment: Я уже разобрался, но всё равно спасибо что вы отозвались!